# Resolving nested Map in @ConfigurationProperties using underscores

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties

Using spring-boot 1.4.6, I'm trying to configure custom properties using underscores and camel-case instead of hyphen and periods. This is due to us passing the properties as system variables and the used shell does not allow hyphens or periods for variable names. This is the properties bean (getters/setter created by lombok):

```
@Data
@Accessors(prefix = "")
@ConfigurationProperties("image.variations")
public class ImageVariationsProperties {

    private Map<String, VariationsHost> hosts;

    @Data
    public static class VariationsHost {            

        private Map<String, Variation> variations;
    }

    @Data
    public static class Variation {

        private int maxWidth;
        private int maxHeight;

    }

}
```

This all works fine for configurations like

```
image.variations.hosts:
  default:
    variations:
      small:
        max-width: 360
        max-height: 220
      medium:
        max-width: 750
        max-height: 450
      large:
        max-width: 1350
        max-height: 900
```

But breaks e.g. by replacing the last item with

```
image_variations_hosts_default_variations_large_maxHeight: 900
```

showing this error

```
Binding to target ImageVariationsProperties(hosts={default=ImageVariationsProperties.VariationsHost(variations={small=ImageVariationsProperties.Variation(maxWidth=360, maxHeight=220), medium=ImageVariationsProperties.Variation(maxWidth=750, maxHeight=450), large=ImageVariationsProperties.Variation(maxWidth=1350, maxHeight=0)})}) failed:

    Property: image.variations.hosts[default_variations_large_maxHeight]
    Value: 900
    Reason: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.Integer' to required type 'com.acme.ImageVariationsProperties$VariationsHost' for property 'hosts[default_variations_large_maxHeight]'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.Integer' to required type 'com.acme.ImageVariationsProperties$VariationsHost' for property 'hosts[default_variations_large_maxHeight]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

It obviously only resolves the first map value, but shouldn't this work for nested maps as well?

Again, please note that I need to use underscores for the reasons described above and can't use hyphens, periods, brackets and the like.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing the value in all caps?
`IMAGE_VARIATIONS_HOSTS_DEFAULT_VARIATIONS_LARGE_MAXHEIGHT`
should work, according to [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Relaxed-Binding-2.0).

You may also find some more relevant information in the [more general](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-Configuration-Binding) page about configuration binding.

Comment: Yes I've tried, but passing in all caps doesn't work either. Btw. I guess this should rather be a comment than an answer.